# How to make every paragraph in plaintextedit have indent in Pyside6?

Tags: python, pyside, pyside2, pyside6, pyqt6

I want every paragraph in plainTextEdit.text has text-indent.
I tried to use setTextIndent(). But it didn't work.
This is my code

```
from ui2 import Ui_Form
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget
from PySide6 import QtCore,QtGui
from PySide6.QtGui import QTextCursor


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

        doc=self.ui.plainTextEdit.document()
        a=doc.firstBlock().blockFormat()
        a.setTextIndent(100)
        cursor = QTextCursor(doc)
        cursor.setBlockFormat(a)
        cursor.insertText("This is the first paragraph\nThis is the second paragraph")
        print(self.ui.plainTextEdit.document().toPlainText())


app = QApplication([])
mainw = MainWindow()
mainw.show()
app.exec()
```

This is my print:

```
This is the first paragraph
This is the second paragraph
```

which don't have textindent.

Comment: The primal purpose of QPlainTextEdit is performance (see [Difference to QTextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#differences-to-qtextedit)), intended for fast responsiveness and *large* text contents. This means that formatting is reduced to a barely minimum (usually, just font properties). If you need actual [Qt rich text](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext.html) support (which only includes the supported [***basic*** HTML *subset* formatting](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html)), then use QTextEdit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use QTextEdit:

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextEdit
from PySide6.QtGui import QTextCursor

app = QApplication([])

te = QTextEdit()
te.resize(640, 480)
te.show()

cursor = QTextCursor(te.document())
block_format = cursor.blockFormat()
block_format.setTextIndent(100)
cursor.setBlockFormat(block_format)
cursor.insertText("This is the first paragraph\nThis is the second paragraph")

app.exec()
```

[image]